# Is it possible to secure whole Controller in Symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, jms

I am using JMSSecurityExtra bundle for securing methods in my contoller.
But is there any way that i can secure the whole controller with `@Secure`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done as per [Documentaion](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/annotations)

https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/issues/50

> Tip: If you like to secure all actions of the controller with the same
>   rule, you may also specify @PreAuthorize on the class itself. Caution
>   though, this rule is only applied to the methods which are declared in
>   the class.

```
use JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\Annotation\PreAuthorize;

 /** @PreAuthorize("hasRole('A') or (hasRole('B') and hasRole('C'))") */
class MyService
{

    public function secureMethod()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This annotation can only be applied to methods.

You could do it like this though (it's a regex):

```
jms_security_extra:
    method_access_control:
        'AcmeDemoBundle:AdminController:.*Action': 'hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN")'
```

Read the documentation: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSecurityExtraBundle/master/method_security_authorization